# Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time

Tags: kotlin, observable, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, dao

My coroutine not working even I have done everything declared in Android Guide. What's wrong with my code?

**Logcat**

> D/FATAL EXCEPTION LOGCAT: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
>
> D/FATAL EXCEPTION LOGCAT: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound
> must be positive

The second exception is something with my Random() I think but couldn't figure out what's happening.

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
        viewModel.allWordAggregate.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner) { items ->
        items.let {
            try {
                val random = Random().nextInt(it.size)
                val randomWordAggregate = it.elementAt(random)
                _randomWordAggregate = randomWordAggregate
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("FATAL EXCEPTION LOGCAT", e.toString())
            }
        }
    }
```

**WordViewModel.kt**

```
    val allWordAggregate: LiveData<List<WordAggregate>> =
    wordDao.getWordsWithMeanings().asLiveData()
```

**WordDao.kt**

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM word")
fun getWordsWithMeanings(): Flow<List<WordAggregate>>
```

Comment: not familiar with this language, but I would wonder what you are getting for random? maybe log it out. it seems like you may be getting a negative number which doesn't work. also what is "it"? (it.elementAt) it's not defined anywhere.

Comment: @Rick I'm trying to get a random item from my word table. "it" is a list of WordAggregate.

Comment: `it.size` can be 0 and `nextInt(it.size)` will throw an exception

Comment: @oguzata is it possible your random number is negative? also is it possible the "word" table has such a huge number of entries as to slow down your UI while querying? also, is it possible it is executing that code for each word in the database?

Comment: @IR42 probably but as you can see I'm using live data which means It will start reading the item from the database and publish it through the live data once it's ready. The problem is occurring because of my return type is "WordAggregate" which is intermediate data class. When I replace it with another entity class my coroutine works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

In **WordDao.kt**, remove `@Transaction` and try

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM word")
suspend fun getWordsWithMeanings(): Flow<List<WordAggregate>>
```

For Random, check if list is empty or not

```
viewModel.allWordAggregate.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner) { items ->
    val list = List<String>()
    if (items.isNotEmpty) {
        val random = Random().nextInt(list.size)
        val randomWordAggregate = list.elementAt(random)
        _randomWordAggregate = randomWordAggregate
    }
}
```

Comment: The list you have declared is always empty. And my main problem is something with my return type "WordAggregate". When I replace return type of it with another entity class my coroutine works flawlessly even though I don't change getWordsWithMeanings() function to suspend function.

Comment: Can you show results of problem

Comment: There is no problem or exception after I change return type of 
fun getWordsWithMeanings(): Flow<List<WordAggregate>>
to
fun getWordsWithMeanings(): Flow<List<Word>>.
WordAggregate is an intermediate data class whereas Word is an entity class. But in my case I want to use WordAggregate not Word. What is the problem?